# Adding force to one object adds force to all objects with script attached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script that moves objects up and down on the y axis only when the mouse is on the object. I am using ray casts and I can use the name and distinguish between each object. However, when I try to add a force when ray casting, all of the objects with the script attached move. Anyone know why this is?

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BlockMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool dragOccuring = false;
    private Vector3 lastMousePosition = Vector2.zero;
    private float amountToMove = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) == true) {
            dragOccuring = true;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                print (hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

            }

        } else if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) == true) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                print (hit.collider.gameObject.name);

                Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

                if (lastMousePosition.y > mousePosition.y){
                    rigidbody.AddForce (0, -Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
                } else if (lastMousePosition.y == mousePosition.y){
                    rigidbody.AddForce (0, 0, 0);
                }
                else{
                    rigidbody.AddForce (0, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
                }

                lastMousePosition = mousePosition;
            }
        } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0) == true) {
            dragOccuring = true;
            lastMousePosition = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to compare the object hit by the ray cast with the script game object. Without this, all the objects with this script attached will move when you click an object on the screen.

Try changing your second **if** block to something like

```
} else if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) == true) {
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
        print (hit.collider.gameObject.name);

        // If this is the clicked object
        if(hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject){
            Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

            if (lastMousePosition.y > mousePosition.y){
                rigidbody.AddForce (0, -Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
            }else if (lastMousePosition.y == mousePosition.y){
                rigidbody.AddForce (0, 0, 0);
            }else{
                rigidbody.AddForce (0, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
            }
        }
        lastMousePosition = mousePosition;
    }
} else if ...
```

You could even do better and check this earlier on your script, so your function would end faster for the object not clicked.